# How to Save Entity with Relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

*I'm new to Core Data, so go easy on me. :) I'm currently using iOS 7 in Xcode 5.*

I have two Entities: **Aircraft** and **Entry**. There is a **one aircraft** to **many entry** relationship.

I'm trying to save a new Entry which has an aircraft object in it. Here is my `Entry.h` file (minus the `#import`):

```
//  Entry.h
@class Aircraft;

@interface Entry : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *duration;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *flightDate;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) Aircraft *aircraft;
@end
```

Meanwhile, over in my view controller where I save the new Entry, I have the following code. I use a dictionary to set up my data prior to creating a new record:

```
//Add New Entry
Aircraft *aircraft = [Aircraft new];
aircraft.aircraftRegistration = _aircraftRegistrationTextField.text;

NSDictionary *newEntry = @{
  @"aircraft": aircraft, //???
  @"flightDate": [formatter dateFromString:_flightDateTextField.text],
  @"duration": [PPHelpers convertHHMMtoDecimal:_durationTextField.text],
};

//Save new Entry to Core Data
PPAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[item setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:newEntry];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

I get a couple errors from this:

`CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Aircraft'`

and...

`-[Aircraft setAircraftRegistration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110b0b550`

I suspect the issue is that I'm not adding the Aircraft to the Entry in the right way.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Aircraft *aircraft = [Aircraft new];
```

creates an object without calling the designated initializer. You should replace it by

```
Aircraft *aircraft = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Aircraft" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

*Note:* It is possible to set Core Data attributes with `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary`,
but a more direct, type-safe and less error-prone way would be to use the Core Data
accessors:

```
Entry *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry" inManagedObjectContext:context];
entry.aircraft = aircraft; // from above
entry.duration = ...;
entry.flightData = ...;
```

Comment: One quick follow up question. Using the above creates a whole new Aircraft record. I just want this to reference the Aircraft Registration of an *existing* Aircraft record. Should I not be inserting a new Aircraft afterall? How do I point to an existing record?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum: Either you keep a pointer to your existing Aircraft object, or you have to execute an NSFetchRequest to fetch the wanted record.

Comment: Ah, I see. Similar to when I edit a record vs. saving a new one. I just pass in the existing NSManagedObject and Core Data knows what to do. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR thanks for comment above ("Note: It is possible to set Core Data attributes with setValuesForKeysWithDictionary, but a more direct, type-safe and less error-prone way would be to use the Core Data accessors").  Can you please help explain why setValuesForKeysWithDictionary is more error-prone?  I have many CD attributes and wish to avoid typing individual Core Data accessors.  Thank you. PS: at the moment, SetValuesForKeysWithDict is giving me the following error: "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x12e924000> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Comment: @MikeLondonUK: That's exactly what I meant. `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary ` *crashes at runtime* if the dictionary contains any key which does not correspond to a property of the entity. When using the accessor methods, the *compiler* checks the correctness of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

if Aircraft is an parent relation entity, you need to use instanciate it by insertNewObjectForEntityForName it's the same that Entry.

```
//Save new Entry to Core Data
PPAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];



//Add New aircraft
Aircraft* aircraft = (Aircraft*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[NSClassFromString(Aircraf) inManagedObjectContext:context];
aircraft.aircraftRegistration = _aircraftRegistrationTextField.text;


Entry* item = (Entry*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSClassFromString(Entry) inManagedObjectContext:context];

[item setAircraft:aircraft];
[item setFlightDate:[formatter dateFromString:_flightDateTextField.text]];
[item setDuration:[PPHelpers convertHHMMtoDecimal:_durationTextField.text]];


NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer is pretty close to Martin's.